# checkBox в QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, checkbox, виджет

Привет Всем. Как отобразить checkBox в заголовке TableWidget ? считать его состоянии, и если он true(стоит галочка) например вывести содержимое этой конкретной колонки в файл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этого можно достичь при помощи `QHeaderView`, и метода `QTableWidget->setHorizontalHeader()`.

Можно следовать следующими шагами:

Создать класс заголовка вашей таблицы, например:

```
class MyTableHeader : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyHeaderView(QWidget* parent)
        : QHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, parent) {}
    // ...
};
```

Этот класс будет использоваться как заголовок для вашей таблицы:

```
MyHeaderView* header = new MyHeaderView();
tableWidget->setHorizontalHeader(header);
```

Для того чтобы ваш header отображался как checkbox, вам необходимо пере-определить метод `QHeaderView::paintSection()`, и там обозначить: где, и какой тип вы хотите отобразить (подсказка: воспользуйтесь классом `QStyleOptionButton` а также свойствами `QStyle::State_On` и `QStyle::State_Off`).

Чтобы считывать состояния, добавьте private переменную, например, `private: bool _isOn;`, и каждый раз, когда user нажимает в перелах вашей checkbox, изменяйте переменную на противоположную. Для этого надо пере-определить класс `QHeaderView::mousePressEvent()`. Эта переменная должна быть также использованна в `paintSelection()` методе, чтобы нарисовать checkbox с правильным состоянием.

Чтобы происходило какое-то определённое действие на появление галочки, воспользуйтесь системой слотов и сигналов, примерно так:

```
void MyTableHeader::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
    // ...
    if (/* произошло нажатие, и галочка включенна */)
        emit checkIsOn();
}
```

На забудьте соединить сигнал `checkIsOn()` со слотом, где вы выводите содержимое в файл.

Comment: Спасибо! попробую)